# SQL Server 2000/2005 - Maintaining Development Version and Production Version

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ddl

I am used to using Oracle Designer by creating database object definitions, then creating DDL SQL required by connecting to a database instance.

For eaxmple, when adding a new column to a table, first I add it to the table definition, then generate the DDL SQL against the development version and run it, then after testing I point to the Production instance to create the missing column in Production.

Given that there is no Designer in SQL Server what is the correct procedure to say add a column to both database instances?  Is there a tool for keeping the schemas in sync?

Comment: Oracle Designer + SQL Server?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085783/sql-server-2005-syncing-development-production-databases/3247904#3247904
basically the same question. I added an answer that shows some free tools. Not going to post it on both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedGate offer a product called SQL Compare, that can be used to script out the differences between different databases.

See: http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm

You could also use the Database Diagrams within SQL Server Management Studio to design your database schema however this would be constrained to within a given database.

Comment: OK - I think I will see how Oracle Designer works with SQL Server as my company won't spend money at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in tool for keeping them in sync (that I know of), but RedGate has some commercial apps for this.

What do you mean there is no designer in SQL Server? Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Sorry I meant no Oracle Designer Application.